# Fortrans equivalent syntax to C++

Tags: c++, optimization, fortran, benchmarking, linear-programming

I am handling a file . THe format of content is as following :

```
name   - problem name (A string value)
m      - number or rows (int value)
n      - number of columns (int value)
Ap     - pointers to the begining of storage of column (size n+1)(an array of size (n+1) )
Ai     - row indices for each non zero entry (input, nnz A)
Ax     - non zero entries (input, nnz A)
b      - right hand side (input, size m)(an double array of size m )
c      - objective vector (minimize, size n) (an double array of size n) )
z0     - initial fixed value for objective (double value)
lobnd  - lower bounds on variables (size n) (an double array of size n )
upbnd  - upper bounds on variables (size n) (an double array of size n )
```

The syntax for reading this file in fortran is as follows :

```
Ap (j) = location of start of column j
Ai (Ap (j)) through Ai (Ap (j+1)-1) are the row indices in column j
Ax (Ap (j)) through Ax (Ap (j+1)-1) are the numerical values in column j

      read(file,'(a8)') name
      read(file,*) m,n
      read(file,*) (ia(i),i=1,n+1)
      read(file,*) (ja(i),i=1,ia(n+1)-1)
      read(file,*) (a(i),i=1,ia(n+1)-1)
      read(file,*) (b(i),i=1,m)
      read(file,*) (c(i),i=1,n)
      read(file,*) z0
      read(file,*) (lobnd(i),i=1,n)
      read(file,*) (upbnd(i),i=1,n)
```

I want to know the corresponding syntax in C++ . Do anyone has any idea how to convert this program from fortran to C++ ? 
[Here is an example of an file .](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/hager/LPTest/LPFormat/blend)

**According to the description of file format here in the above file**

```
name   = 'BLEND'
m      = 74  
n      = 114
upbnd  = I can see the n or 114 double values at the end of the file
lobnd  = I can see the n or 114 double values before the values of upbnd  
z0     = here I can see 0. is the value of z0
c      = I can see n or 114 values before z0 in the file and understand this
b      = I understand the right hand side and I can see the m or 74 values
Ai     - I understand row indices for each non zero entry (input, nnz A)
Ax     - non zero entries (input, nnz A)

Now I can not understand the following values in the file:
Ap     = I can not understand what do these (n+1) or 115 integers mean
```

I want to understand this Ap values in the file. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some files link

Comment: **Wrong approach.** Don't code in C++ while thinking in Fortran. Spend weeks reading some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and use standard C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: I know C++ . But I do not know Fortran .

Comment: @MattP , I have read all data of this file except a(i,j) array . What is the meaning of this line ? "read(file,*) (ia(i),i=1,n+1)"

Comment: read up on "list directed input" and "implied do loops" that will help you understand that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read(file,'(a8)') name` translates roughly like `scanf("%8s", name);`.

The `read(file,*) m,n` is roughly equivalent to something like `file >> m >> n;`

The lines like `read(file,*) (ia(i),i=1,n+1)` are undoubtedly the trickiest. The part after the first comma is an "implied DO loop". It basically means this is roughly equivalent to something on the order of:

```
for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++)
    file >> ia[i];
```

I believe the rest are just repetitions of one or another of those shown above.

There is one other point to keep in mind, though: Fortran stores arrays in column major order. C and C++ store arrays in row-major order. That means as you traverse an array in C or C++, you normally want to traverse it row by row. This will, among other things, optimize cache usage, because each row is stored contiguously in memory.

Fortran is column-major. That means each column is contiguous in memory, and the natural way to traverse the array is a column at a time. Since each column is contiguous in memory, this (of course) optimizes cache usage.

The values in Ap contain the location of the beginning of each column. That is Ap(1) is the index of the first item in the first column. Ap(2) is the index of the first item in the second column, and so on. If you need to read the N<sup>th</sup> column, Ap(N) will tell you the spot in the main array where you start to read to get the data for that column. Since Ap(N+1) is the beginning of column N+1, the last item in column N is at Ap(N+1)-1.

So, let's assume you read the main data array into a flat (1D) array, which we'll just call `data`. To read the N<sup>th</sup> column in `data`, you can use `Ap`. For example, to print out the N<sup>th</sup> column, we could write code like this:

```
void print_column(int n) {
    for (int i=Ap[n]; i<Ap[n+1]; i++)
        std::cout << data[i] << '\t';
}
```

This lets you avoid having to deal with dynamically allocating a 2D array, and instead use only single `new`/`malloc`/`vector` to hold the data, along with a second one to hold the index for the beginning of each column. In C++ it's pretty easy to create a 2D matrix class that overloads `operator()` to do 2D addressing into data stored in a `vector`. You could use either the extra level of indirection provided by `Ap`, or you could just use multiplication to get to the right position. On a current processor, the multiplication is probably faster than a memory reference, but on older processors multiplication was often much slower relative to memory access.

Comment: Can you give an example to Ap ?